# Remove characters from end of URL

Tags: php

Say I have a URL with something like this:

`http://website.com/website/webpage/?message=newexpense`

I have the following code to try and get the the URL before the question mark:

```
$post_url = $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$link_before_question_mark = explode('?', $actual_link);
$add_income_url = $link_before_question_mark[0];
```

In this example I would get the following URL:

`http://website.com/website/webpage/`

I'd like to remove the webpage portion of this so the URL is:

`http://website.com/website/`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a similar trick using `explode`. Then pop the parts you don't need and `implode` the url back together. If you are sure that the part after '?' never contains a '/', you can replace your code with this one. If you're not sure, you should first remove the part after '/' and then run this code to remove the last part of the path.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://website.com/website/webpage/?message=newexpense';

$parts = explode('/', $url);

// Remove the last part from the array
$lastpart = array_pop($parts);

// If the last part is empty, or the last part starts with a '?'
// this means there was a '/' at the end of the url, so we 
// need to pop another part.
if ($lastpart == '' or substr($lastpart, 0, 1) == '?')
  array_pop($parts);

$url = implode('/', $parts);

var_dump($url);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) This way you have all components.

```
$url = 'http://website.com/website/webpage/?message=newexpense';
$pUrl = parse_url( $url);
echo $pUrl['scheme'] . '://' . $pUrl['host'] . $pUrl['path'];
```

Comment: Yes, parse_url is a good way of separating things. Note that in this case you still need to strip the "webpage" part off to get to the desired URL from the question, though.

Comment: Agree. It is a matter of what else you need to do. If I have a uri including a query then I expect it to be used at some point in the script so like to get everything available in one go. But if there is no other use then dirname certainly gets the job done nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use [`dirname`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php); it's specifically designed to strip the last stuff after a "/"...

```
$url = "http://website.com/website/webpage/?message=newexpense";
echo dirname(dirname($url))."/"; // "http://website.com/website/"
```

(As it says in the documentation, "dirname() operates naively on the input string, and is not aware of the actual filesystem...", so it's quite safe to use for this kind of purpose.)

Answer (score 0):

Try it with explode

```
<?php
$actual_link = "http://website.com/website/webpage/?message=newexpense]";
$link_before_question_mark = explode('?', $actual_link);
$add_income_url = $link_before_question_mark[0];
$split=explode('/',  $add_income_url);
echo $split[0]."//".$split[2]."/".$split[3]."/";

?>
```

Even better is...

```
<?php
$actual_link = "http://website.com/website/webpage/?message=newexpense]";
$split=explode('/',  $actual_link);
echo $split[0]."//".$split[2]."/".$split[3]."/";

?>
```